# Change Apache Roller URL Structure

Tags: apache-roller

I have one existing website and want to migrate to Apache Roller CMS.

Existing website url is following

http://www.xx.com/blog/2015/03/how_to_change_the_url_structure

Can I able to use the same url structure in Roller CMS, otherwise it is problematic for SEO perspective?

If any solution for this problem is highly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean you want the monthly prefix (/2015/03/) to permalink of each blog entry? If so, Unfortunately, I think Roller doesn't support such URL structure. If you want it you can tweak the source code of Roller as you like (You can download the entire source code from our website http://roller.apache.org/downloads/downloads.html). I think it's not hard as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with Roller's URL structure for new blog entries that will be written after the migration, I recommend you to set up a redirecting filter such as Apache + mod_rewrite, and redirect all of requests to older weblog entries to Roller's URL structure. For example, With this redirecting filter, the request to your existing entry

http://www.example.com/blog/2015/03/how_to_change_the_url_structure

Will be redirected to Roller's URL scheme:

http://www.example.com/blog/username/entry/2015_03_how_to_change_the_url_structure

You can set "anchor" of your weblog entry (for this example, the anchor is "2015_03_how_to_change_the_url_structure") in the time of migration as you like. Roller stores its weblog entries in a database table named "weblogentry" and stores the anchor in a column which named "anchor".

Comment: Can I able to remove the "entry" from the above URL? do you know which class is appending the "entry" if it is I could able to change this from URL and build the package. Also I have checked the database but there is no "entry" in the table

Comment: In Roller URL scheme, "entry" is the indication of permalink which is hard coded inside several of Java code such as https://github.com/apache/roller/blob/a016635d334f2901b2fe9e1c0b6324dc81cf6bc6/app/src/main/java/org/apache/roller/weblogger/ui/rendering/util/WeblogPageRequest.java#L123
. As for your question, If you are willing to tweak the codebase you can change or remove "entry" but take care of conflict with other labels of URL such as "date", "category" and "tags" etc.